# Fullcalendar - custom timeline and event slots for resource view "Rooms/Shifts"

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-6

Is it possible and how to achive such scheduler view:

[image]

There are always 2 shifts per day. Day/Shift is single slot for multiple events.
We are using pro version with [Timeline View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/timeline-view)

Comment: You can't call it day shift and night shift (because fullcalendar doesn't allow naming of timeslots), but you could certainly have two 12-hour timeslots per day

Comment: Actually, you can. Fullcalendar has undocumented option `slotLabelContent` which do the trick. Works same as https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection
Documentation is poor.

Comment: You should add the details as an Answer below then, in case it's useful to other people. I'd only say: beware using undocumented features in case the developer didn't intend them to be public and therefore might change or remove them in a future version without any warning.

Comment: Although now that I look a bit closer, it appears slotLabelContent is in fact mentioned here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks . So you should be OK. And apologies for not spotting it earlier and claiming it wasn't possible. Please do add your solution in the Answers section and I will happily upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable.

Option "[slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat)" controls how the time and date cells are labelled, here's an example:

```
slotLabelFormat: [
  { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }, // top level of text
  { hour: 'numeric' } // lower level of text
],
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/acerix/pen/eYbEQVb?editors=001).

This allows to create 2 row header.

The "[slotDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration)" setting controls the size of the slots. This allow to split columns into 2 (or more) periods per day. If you need the shifts to be less than 12 hours you can change that and set [slotMinTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinTime)/slotMaxTime to hide the other hours.

```
slotDuration: {
  hours: 12
},
```

And there is also "[slotLabelContent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks)" to customize the labels. It can be used same way as "[content-injection](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection)".
This can be function triggered each time label is displayed.
This way hour label may be changed for shifts names or whatever is needed.

```
/** @param {SlotLabelContentArg} arg */
slotLabelContent: arg => {
   arg.level; // Label level
   arg.text; // Original label text - depends on slotLabelFormat & slotDuration
   arg.date; // slot Date object

   return arg.text;
}
```

Comment: slotLabelContent is documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks, as I mentioned previously. Aside from that, good answer.

Comment: I _did_ correct it. And improve it. Why should it not be edited? I don't understand your point, sorry.

Comment: `I posted it and did improvements immediately`... [as far as I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77242869/revisions) you didn't add anything that I didn't also add. So nothing meaningful was lost. I appreciate you may have seen my comment and then decided to edit it, but at the same time I also noticed a couple of other things that could be improved so I decided to edit it myself anyway. It's just an accident, no malice intended. Often in my experience people don't hang around immediately after posting anyway, I wasn't necessarily expecting you to view my comment instantaneously

Comment: P.S. If the editor software detects simultaneous conflicting edits it will generally prevent the second submitter (which was me as you can see from the history) from submitting their changes. in this case presumably it deemed them similar enough not to matter.